# How to query junction table in EF without it being defined (performance issue)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

The classic User-UserRole-Role example

The **UserProfile** class:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The **Role** class:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

With additional `FluentAPI` mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Users).WithMany(u => u.Roles)
    .Map(m => 
        m.MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("UserId").ToTable("UserInRole"));
```

Entity Framework Code First generates the database tables `UserProfile`, `Role` and `UserInRole`. `UserInRole` table contains only `RoleId` and `UserId` keys.

**Problem/Need:** I need a list of users paired with their roles, but only for a specific list of users and roles.

I solved this problem by first getting the users and then get their Roles, but it seems to be much less performant way (as it seems it does many round-trips to the DBMS).

In SQL, I would do this:

```
select u.UserName, r.Name from UserInRole as ur
left outer join UserProfile as u on ur.UserId = u.Id 
left outer join Role as r on ur.RoleId = r.Id
where u.Id in (1, 2, 3) and r.Id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**If possible, how can I do that in EntityFramework?** (*Note that I do not have the junction table `UserInRole` mapped in Code First?*) None of the LINQ queries I tried generated the two left outer joins from the junction table, and as far as I could see, this would be the fastest way. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In your SQL query what tables are `u` and `p` coming from?

Comment: u is userProfile, and p was from Privilege which was renamed to Role, but I failed to correctly replace all p references with r. Thanks for pointing that out - I have now fixed the query in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, why didn't you map `UserInRole` in code first?

Comment: I am not sure. That's what bugs me. Can I map this table in addition to preserving mapping for User.Roles and Roles.Users? The reason of thought was that if I map the junction table, I would lose the navigation properties from user directly to its roles, and from role to its users. Would I be able to take both approaches simultaneously (preserving direct access and mapping junction table at the same time)?

Comment: In the exact way that you have it right now? No, I don't think that that's possible. You would have to go through the junction object to do so. That being said, you could always create a `[NotMapped]` navigation property that would return just the roles from the collection of junction objects. If you want, I could put an example of that as an answer.

Comment: I don't think that would be an answer to my question, but you can write an answer that describes that the solution must include the junction table with an explanation of why that is. I am also worried about performance, so any feedback on performance would be appreciated.